# What font typically used below image?

Tags: adobe-photoshop, fonts

Please help to identify the below font so that i can reproduced same looking result. Thanks in advance your kind effort.

[image]

Answer (score 3):

Thats Monotype Corsova. It comes with windows or office. I finally knew one!!! The system works.